# Algorithm to fire sequential keystrokes

Tags: algorithm

I want to write an algorithm to sequentially press keys F1-F3. My form has these controls:

```
lblF1
textboxF1
lblF2
textboxF2
lblF3
textboxF3
btnStart
```

In textboxF1-textboxF3 the time in seconds is entered. This when the program is to press the hotkey. It is important that the program can't press two keys at once, for example F1 and F2. It may not press more than one key in a second. When I click on btnStart it calls Run().

This is how I tried to resolve this:

```
static int counterF1 = 9999;
static int counterF2 = 9999;
static int counterF3 = 9999;

    public void Run()
    {
        counterF1 = 9999;
        counterF2 = 9999;
        counterF3 = 9999;
        while (true)
        {
            Loop();
        }
    }

    public void Loop()
    {
        bool used = false;

            if (counterF1 >= (int)textboxF1.text)
            {
                counterF1 = PressKey(VK_F1);
                used = true;
            }

            if (counterF2 >= (int)textboxF2.text)
            {
                counterF2 = PressKey(VK_F2);
                used = true;
            }

            if (counterF3 >= (int)textboxF3.text)
            {
                counterF3 = PressKey(VK_F3);
                used = true;
            }
        if (used == false)
        {
            IncrementCounters();
            Delay(1000);
        }
    }

    public double PressKey(uint key)
    {
        myPostMessageA(hWindow, WM_KEYDOWN, (uint)key, (uint)key); 
        IncrementCounters();
        return 1; //return 1 because one second
    }

    public void IncrementCounters()
    {
        counterF1++;
        counterF2++;
        counterF3++;
    }
```

But often it doesn't press any key (it is possible it is too late, but can't be an omission). Can you explain how to make an algorithm for this?

Comment: With `static int counterF1 = 9999;` and similar expressions in your methods you declare a new local variable. Leave the `static int` away.

Comment: you're right, errors in my pseudocode. In source file it's correctly. I edited my code here.

Comment: Some general hints: I don't really get, what you want. Try to explain it a bit clearer. Don't use `break` in a while loop, if you can use the precondition for that. If you send WM_KEYDOWN, also send WM_KEYUP. If you want to perform a periodic task, use a timer instead of an infinite loop.

Comment: For example, I want to press F1 in every second and F2 in every 5 second. So, I want to press F1, F1, F1, F1, F1, F2, F1, F1, F1, F1, F2, F1 etc. and between pressing is one second delay. If I will use timer, sometimes program will can press F1 and F2 in this same second, and it isn't desired. In my code I'm using WM_KEYUP, here I didn't put it to shorter code. Here is like pseudocode to present my alghoritm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will use a class `KeyStroke` that stores the necessary data for a special key:

```
public class KeyStroke
{
    public int period { get; set; } // Period in which to hit key
    public int next { get; set; } // ticks to the next hit of this key
    public int VK { get; set; } //KeyCode
}
public List<KeyStroke> keys = new List<KeyStroke>();
```

An Initialize() method is needed to read the data from the text boxes and to init the simulation. We utilize a timer with the interval of one second to run the simulation. In my example, I don't read from textboxes, but use constant values. Add the input and error handling. If you use WPF, you can bind the KeyStroke objects to the textboxes.

```
void Init()
{
    //Initialize keys with according periods from input
    keys.Clear();
    keys.Add(new KeyStroke() { VK = VK_F1, period = 1, next = 1 });
    keys.Add(new KeyStroke() { VK = VK_F2, period = 10, next = 10 });
    keys.Add(new KeyStroke() { VK = VK_F3, period = 5, next = 5 });

    //sort keys by period (descending), in order to handle long period keys, too
    keys.Sort((first, second) => second.period.CompareTo(first.period));

    //Start the program
    var t = new DispatcherTimer();
    t.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
    t.Tick += new EventHandler(t_Tick);
    t.Start();
}
```

The tick event is similar to yours:

```
void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool used = false;
    foreach (var key in keys)
    {
        if (key.next <= 0 && !used)
        {
            PressKey(key.VK);
            key.next = key.period;
            used = true;
        }
        key.next--;
    }
}
```

Comment: This method will prevent the press of two keys in one second?

Comment: Yes, the `used` variable prevents two keys from being pressed in the same cycle.

Comment: "keys" variable is type of list?

Comment: Oh, forgot that. I edited the answer. You can also use an array for that.

Comment: Hmm... One time when I will run it, it's working perfectly. But more times it's pressing more than one key in the same second, I don't know why... When I set F1 to 1 sec, F2 in 6 seconds, It pressing F1 in every second and F2 in every two seconds...

Comment: Do you clear the `keys` list? If there are more keys in the list, then they will be pressed more often. Furthermore, you have to stop the timer, if you want to restart.

Comment: I have more keys on the list, F1 to F10, 0 to 9 and alt+0 to alt+9. Rest is same like in your code. I'm clearing the list always when I initialize list.

Comment: And the timer? You have to make it a class variable in order to be able to stop it.

Comment: You're right. I declated timer as global variable and initialize t = new DispatcherTimer(); only one time. I move it to initialize function and it's working correctly.